# Bregman Projection on Constrained Simplex

Tags: probability, algorithms, convex-optimization

Consider the Bregman divergence induced by negative entropy function
$$
D_h(x||y) = -\sum x_i + \sum y_i +\sum x_i\ln \frac{x_i}{y_i} 
$$

Given a constrained simplex $K_\alpha = [x\in [\alpha,1]^d | \sum x_i = 1]$ with $\alpha\in [0,1/d]$. What is the Bregman projection of a non-negative vector $y$ to $K_\alpha$? In other words, given $y\in R_+^d$, what is $y^+$ defined as
$$
y^+ = \arg \min_{x\in K_\alpha} D_h(x||y)
$$
?

---

It's known that when $\alpha=0$, $y^+ = \frac{y}{||y||_1}$. I am wondering if there is a closed form for $y^+$ for general $\alpha$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried duality, like the standard approach of projecting onto the unit simplex via the Euclidean norm? Give one Lagrange multiplier to the equality constraint. Get a concave dual in one variable. Solve by bysection --> use the primal-dal relationship to solve the primal.